SSR and api layer in nextjs
I have trying to start using react to build a website, and I had only been using traditional react SPAs so far. Now I wanted to use a framework and stumbled upon Next.js and it's SSR components.
I have the following confusions:

It appears Next uses SSR by default. And, to use client components I have to declare the use client directive.    But, in this post, someone mentions if we don't use getServerSideProps or getStaticProps then nextjs will use CSR. So, I'm not understanding if this behaviour of Next is configurable to the point where it mimics the traditional React behaviour where
server provides everything on the client side (with the single app
bundle), not compromising it's other benifits like routing, image optimization etc. ? OR, we gotta declare this on each and every page/component so that we can get a fully client side app?

There seem to be a API routes feature and since we have SSR, we may avoid building something like an express backend. But, I would love to keep all my logic on a separate server module with another fw for the backend logic(NestJs). Is this considered bad practise while using Next? Are there any important things I should consider while making a separate express app on the backend but using Next for FE?



You seem to mix quite a lot of different things here so I might suggest you take a look at https://nextjs.org/learn.
Anyways, I'll try to clear up some things:

There are now (since version 13.4 if I'm not mistaken) 2 different routers in NextJS. app or pages decided by which folder you have you code in. App is the newer kid on the block with some new features like loading, nested layout, easier metadata, etc...
SSR is not the same as Server components. SSR will compute everything then send HTML to the client. Server components will run the code inside the component on the server but will still send a React element (some kind of react tree representation) to the client. You can have a page with both Server and Client Components. Client components will send the js to the client for the computation to be done there (quite like react SPA).
Server component is an app router "feature" while SSR (with getServerSideProps or getStaticProps) is a pages router feature.
API route is available in both routers but the setup is a bit different between the 2.
You can have app and pages in the same project as long as route mapping doesn't match both sides.
You don't need another backend if you don't want to (except some special cases) however there is nothing wrong with having one. Though it is usually easier to use API routes (or server actions) to call the external backend. That way you can keep eventual secrets on the server side and won't have any CORS issues.

I hope this clarifies some points for your further research ;)

Thanks for the awesome reply. It does look I have to learn a bit more on nextjs, but, I would like to ask for the rendering part what would I have to do if I wanted for next to fully behave like react? Like fully client side only i.e. send a single app bundle from the server?

I think you should learn a bit more about Next and come back to this later. The question is a bit odd (for me). I probably would answer: don't use NextJS then. First, I don't understand why you would want to do that. Secondly, assuming you have a valid reason, I'm not sure there is a point using NextJS then. That being said, you can wrap the root layout inside a client component and that would do the trick. Or use the pages router without any getServerSideProps
